# JOGL Using Multiple Textures

Tags: textures, jogl

I am trying to load 2 textures and map them to 2 seperate quads.

```
Texture1 = TextureIO.newTexture(cl.getResource(texturePath1), false, null);

Texture2 = TextureIO.newTexture(cl.getResource(texturePath2), false, null);
```

I also tried this:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(texturePath1));

Texture1 = AWTTextureIO.newTexture(GLProfile.getDefault(), image, false);

image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(texturePath2));

Texture2 = AWTTextureIO.newTexture(GLProfile.getDefault(), image, false);
```

But when I bind them with quads, Texture1 has the same texture as Texture2. Second one I loaded always overlap the first one. I made a research but it was useless because the lack of tutorials on JOGL.

This seems a simple problem so can anyone with JOGL knowledge help me?

Comment: You can take inspiration from this [sample](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_320/texture/Gl_320_texture_2d.java)

Comment: There is probably something wrong in your own code, please provide a SSCCE. If the two paths points to two distinct image files, the textures are different and there is no such bug in JOGL. Unfortunately, elect's example is confusing as it uses a non standard API that has nothing to do with JogAmp's JOGL whereas the original poster uses com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture. There are numerous tutorials in our wiki and lots of examples in jogl-demos on Github.

Comment: Ensure that you really bind the texture you want to use by calling Texture.bind(). This example uses the lower level API: https://github.com/sgothel/jogl-demos/blob/master/src/redbook/src/glredbook11/texbind.java It just works. Texture.bind() is equivalent to glBindTexture and it creates the identifier if necessary (glGenTextures()).